# C#でのCOMのShell.Applicationの利用

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

C#でダウンロードフォルダのパスを取得したいと思い、下記のようなソースを記述したのですが、うまく取得できません。  
　一応ネットを調べてみたりしたのですが、うまくいかないので、アドバイスをいただけると幸いです。  
　C#は最近始めたばかりなので、たぶんどこかがおかしいんだとは思いますが。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MainClass{
public static void Main(){
Type instanceType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(instanceType);
dynamic folder = shell.Namespace("shell:Downloads");
dynamic directory = folder.Path();
MessageBox.Show(""+directory);
}
}
```

なお、環境は、Windows10 64ビットです。  
　また、コンパイルはWindows付属の「csc.exe」（.netFramework4用）を利用しています。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> dynamic directory = folder.Path();
> ```

あと一歩でした。[Shellオブジェクト](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094(v=vs.85).aspx)から[Folderオブジェクト](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787868(v=vs.85).aspx)は取得できています。ここで取得できているのは実は[Folder2オブジェクト](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787854(v=vs.85).aspx)でもあるため[Selfプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787860(v=vs.85).aspx)を使用することで[FolderItemオブジェクト](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787810(v=vs.85).aspx)が取得できます。そうすれば素直に[Pathプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787844(v=vs.85).aspx)でフルパスを取得できます。

```
public static void Main() {
    var instanceType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
    dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(instanceType);
    var folder = shell.Namespace("shell:Downloads");
    string directory = folder.Self.Path;
    MessageBox.Show(directory);
}
```

---

ncaqさんはハードコーディングで `Downloads` というパスを提示していますが、ダウンロードフォルダの場所はプロパティダイアログで移動可能なので、ハードコーディングすべきではありません。

[image: ダウンロードフォルダの場所]

Comment: お世話になります。  
　なるほど、Selfが必要だったんですね。  
　助かりました。  
　ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

わざわざCOMを使わなくてもC#向けのWindowsライブラリで取得できるはずです.

例えば

`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads");`

参考: [.net - How to programmatically derive windows downloads folder "%USERPROFILE%/Downloads"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/how-to-programmatically-derive-windows-downloads-folder-userprofile-downloads)

環境構築が面倒なので動作確認はしていません.